# Structuring data in this multidimensional-array

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I am processing images in python and for a specific purpose I've been asked to 
"make numpy arrays with these dimensions: 32x3x512x512 (patches x color channels, height, width)." I don't have any problem getting any of the data, but I just cannot picture the structure of the numpy array. My best approaches are:
[Option 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmCfs.jpg), [Option 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6X8H.jpg) . And I may be not even close.

Any better idea on how the numpy array should look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can literally take the problem description and use it as the shape of the array:

```
arr = np.empty((32, 3, 512, 512), 'u1')
```

Now `arr[0]` is the first patch (i.e. first image), and has the shape `(3, 512, 512)`, so it's 24 (3x8) bits per pixel, and the dimensions are 512 x 512 pixels.

Some people might use a different ordering of the dimensions, such as `(32, 512, 512, 3)`, but it really depends on the processing you eventually want to do.